# Expand/contract loops and if/then statements in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This is annoying problem I'm having in VS2010, is there anyway I can expand and contract conditional statements and loops, as if they were methods? I realize the answer might be that I should be refactoring them out into methods if I get to this point, but humor me anyway. I thought I was once able to do this.

Edit, an example:

```
public void DoSomething() 
{
  if (1 < 2) {
  // long statement here
  }
}
```

In the left gutter of VS2010, I can contract "DoSomething" ... I cannot, however, contract the if/then statement.

Comment: Can you provide an example here?  It's not clear what you're asking for

Comment: I believe the OP is asking if you can simply collapse the code that makes up a block i.e. a `while` loop or `if` statement similar to the way you can collapse regions or methods.

Comment: C/C++ has this feature under Tools > Text Editor > C/C++ > View > Outline Statement Blocks. This also works for bare {} if you don't mind the previous semicolon being collapsed with the block. I decided to use the ugly but cross-platform sequence ;{ /* ... */ } for my "regions."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a VS 2010 plugin that does just that: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4d7e74d7-3d71-4ee5-9ac8-04b76e411ea8

Answer (score 16):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/73948b75-2db6-4662-80fa-5f2ace372a3b/

You can go to Tools menu -> Options. Then go to Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting. Turn the Outline Statement Blocks to true.

Answer (score 1):

Not automatically, as with a method, but select some lines and choose Edit, Outlining, Hide Selection. You can then expand/collapse at will. Stop Hiding will take away the +/- symbol.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with C# you could use #region / #endregion. I'm not sure if these tags are supported in other languages or not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is supported by VS2010.  Could you possibly have been using something like Resharper before?  I use both "vanilla" VS and VS Power Tools, and I don't have this.