# How to have Visual Studio 2010 automatically create collapsable regions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I want to have Visual Studio 2010 automatically create collapsable regions for blocks of code.  I know I can create regions:

```
#region myregion
#endregion
```

However, I want the -/+ sign to appear for loops, try/catch, or any other section that has a beginning and ending without manually creating regions.  I thought I have seen this with other's machines running Visual Studio.  How can I have this feature?  Is there a setting?

Comment: Yes, there is a setting for this. Not at my computer, but I'm sure someone will get you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expand/contract loops and if/then statements in VS2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488797/expand-contract-loops-and-if-then-statements-in-vs2010)

Comment: Brr, name the product so I can be sure to never have to look at that.  Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [C# Outline plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4d7e74d7-3d71-4ee5-9ac8-04b76e411ea8) (found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5192214/61697))

Comment: This is a great solution (thus receiving a +1), unfortunately it supports the collapse of brackets {} only (if, switch,while) and not colons : (case).

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are looking for is called Outlining.  Check the Edit->Outlining menu.  If outlining is disabled you should see a menu item called "Start Automatic Outlining"

Comment: It is turned on but the only automatic outlining I am getting is for the methods, not blocks of code inside of the methods.