# Visual Studio plugin to expand/contract nested (if / elseif / for / while / case etc.) code?

Tags: coding-style, visual-studio, plugins

Sometimes, I have an `if()` section (along with a few `else if()` sections) with a medium or big chunk of code in each 'section' (I think that's called the 'body' inside the { }).

I'd like to be able to contract/collapse or expand those sections. Perhaps a plugin for Visual Studio 2010 exists? And before anyone says "Call an external method instead", I would say:

- That takes unnecessary time to write out the method header
- Makes the code more verbose
- No where else will call that same bit of code. I tend to leave separate methods for occasions where it will be called multiple times.
- It's not 'in place' and will jump to a different part of the document making it (for example) harder to relate to 'nearby' code.

One possibility is `#region`, but that suffers from time/space loss, and unfortunately, VS doesn't save whether the region is contracted or expanded when you reopen the project later.

My C# programs would look a lot tidier if I could have a 'higher-level' view of the code using this technique of contracting `if` 'sections'. So surely someone must have coded a plugin like this?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that C++ in VS2010 can [handle this by default apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5972633/848344), but not C#. Nevertheless, Stackoverflow came to the [rescue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285422/visual-studio-c-sharp-statement-collapsing) and offered this plugin solution which works well. It records the contractions/expansions after reopening the project too:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4d7e74d7-3d71-4ee5-9ac8-04b76e411ea8

(an alternative, less popular plugin can be [found here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/db114790-9561-4f11-93c0-3e24e7c1152e?SRC=VSIDE))